# Разница между `add()` и `replace() + addToBackStack("")` при работе с фрагментами

Tags: android

Будет ли разница при использовании этих подходов?

`add()` и `replace() + addToBackStack("")`

Как по мне результат будет один и тот же

Правильно я понимаю?

Comment: Разница должна быть. В первом случае нижний фрагмент остаётся на экране и будет виден, если у второго прозрачный фон. Во втором случае первый фрагмент будет убран с экрана. Прямо сейчас проверить не могу, но помню что оно как-то так работает)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб ну а в плане `lifecycle` ? Они будут вести себя одинаково?

Comment: По идее также по разному. В первом случае onDestroyView, вроде, не вызовется у 1-ого и при возврате к нему разметка не будет грузиться с нуля, т.е. `onViewCreated()` так же не вызовется. Во втором случае 1-ый фрагмент должен через эти вызовы пройти

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Да, но тогда вопрос. При использовании 2го подхода, мы сохраняем фрагмент в бекстек, но все равно фрагмент проходит по всему лайвсайклу и доходит до `onDestroyView()`, как система знает и как востанавливает этот фрагмент при нажатии `onBack()`? Если фрагмент разрушен... И еще вопрос, как в таком случае сохранять state вью? Если даже при подходе MVVM , вьюмодель так же будет разрушена когда `onDestroy()` фрагмента будет вызвана...

Comment: фрагмент не разрушается при `onDestroyView()`, а при `onDestroy()`. Нажимая назад, его вьюха перерисовывается. ViewModel разрушается при `onDestroy()` фрагмента и флаге `isConfigurationChanges = false`

Comment: @Valgaal то есть вы хотите сказать, что при `replace()` вызывается `onDestroyView()` и `onDestroy()` не вызывается?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`onDestroyView()` - уничтожается View фрагмента, фрагмент живет

`onDestroy()` - уничтожается фрагмент

Их важно отличать, потому что ViewModel уничтожается, когда вызывается `onDestroy()` при условии, что `isConfigurationChanges = false`

Что такое `addToBackStack("tag")`?

Метод для того, чтобы добавить транзакцию в объект, который работает по принципу стека(далее стек). Это нужно для того, чтобы мы могли гибко переключаться между фрагментами. Например, достать из стека фрагмент по тегу.

Частый случай в разработке - это когда, мы нажимает кнопку назад и вызывается метод `popBackStack()`. Что он делает? Он вытаскивает по последней транзакции фрагмент из стека, вызывает последовательно `onDestroyView()`, потом `onDestroy()`. Если view во фрагменте уже уничтожена, то он сразу вызовет `onDestroy()`

Теперь, что такое `add()`. Добавляет поверх фрагмент(вызываются `onCreate()`, `onCreateView`) Что будет с предыдущими фрагментами на экране? Ничего. Они будут жить, и их view тоже.

Что такое `replace()` Заменяет view **всех** фрагментов на экране. То есть у нас вызовется `onDestroyView()` у всех фрагментов, которые он заменил. Но сами фрагменты будут живы.

Когда еще вызывается `onDestroy()` у фрагмента? Кроме `popBackStack()` я знаю еще один случай, когда уничтожается активити, в которой находятся эти фрагменты.

Вот несколько примеров.

Первый пример:

```
FragmentOne add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
FragmentTwo .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment2).commit();

FragmentOne onCreateView()
FragmentOne onDestroyView()
FragmentTwo onCreateView()
Нажимаю назад
FragmentOne onDestroy()
```

Второй пример:

```
FragmentOne add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();
FragmentTwo .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment2).addToBackStack(null).commit();

FragmentOne onCreateView()
FragmentOne onDestroyView()
FragmentTwo onCreateView()
Нажимаю назад
FragmentTwo onDestroyView()
FragmentTwo onDestroy()
```

Третий пример:

```
FragmentOne add(R.id.fragment_container,fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
FragmentTwo add(R.id.fragment_container,fragment2).commit();

FragmentOne onCreateView()
FragmentTwo onCreateView()
Нажимаю назад
FragmentOne onDestroyView()
FragmentOne onDestroy()
```

Comment: А зачем при использовании `add()` делать `addToBackStack()` ? Он и так будет в стеке если нажимаем назад... Так ведь?

Comment: Нет, не будет. В стек добавляет метод addToBackStack(). `add()` добавляет фрагмент поверх предыдущего и все

Comment: Ну так бекстек нужен для того, что при нажатии кнопки back юзер мог вернуться на предыдущий фрагмент... Тогда зачем нам при использовании `add()` (что гарантирует если юзер нажмет back то он вернется на предыдущий фраг) добавлять еще и `addToBackStack()`? Вот в чем вопрос

Comment: Сделайте два подряд фрагмента  с `add()` в активити. И нажмите кнопку назад, по вашей логике, мы должны увидеть первый фрагмент, но вы выйдете из активити  и закроете приложение, потому что стек пустой

Comment: Да вы правы я перепутал. Все верно. Но вот, что еще интересно. Допустим мы добавили 2 фрагмента `add().addToBackStack()` и потом еще один `replace().addToBackStack()` и нажали back... То из за того, что метод `replace()` вызывает `onDestroyView()` у всех остальных фрагментов то вернувшись на предыдущий фрагмент мы не увидим view этого фрагмента, так как оно было уничтожено, а метод `onCreateView()` при условии, что фрагмент был добавлен методом `add()` не вызывается. Как в такой ситуации сохранять view state?

Comment: Методы `onCreateView()` вызовутся у двух фрагментов. Это значит, что экраны перересуются заново, но фрагменты будут жить. Сохранить данные можно в глобальных полях фрагмента (в вызовe `onDestroyView` присваиваете какие-то данные глобальным полям) или во ViewModel обычным MVVM(главное подписываться не на `this`, а на `this.viewLifecycleOwner`)